# numerical integration of a numerical differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a numerical function F (list of complex data) in two variables z and x . The coordinates z and x are the lists also, in these ranges 
z={0.025,0.03}, x=(0.075,0.08}  and I tried to find this integration :
(∬(conjugate F* (z(∂F/∂x)-x(∂F/∂z )) dz dx) / (∫∫|f|^2   dz dx)

firstly, I interpolated F,and then get the conjugate F but then I couldn't find a way to evaluate the differentiation of F

Then I tried to get the command for the integration which depends on the differentiation.but I have many problems. Please can anyone help me to evaluate the equation above.

this is the list data of F:

```
    f={-0.0129036 - 0.00586097 I, -0.00949092 - 0.00489795 I, -0.00607024 - 
    0.00393027 I, -0.00264156 - 0.00295789 I, 
  0.000795063 - 0.00198079 I, 0.00423958 - 0.00099891 I, 
  0.00769193 - 0.0000122331 I, 0.0111521 + 0.000979279 I, 
  0.01462 + 0.00197566 I, 0.0180955 + 0.00297695 I, 
  0.0215787 + 0.00398317 I, -0.0131653 - 0.00556511 I, -0.00975679 - 
   0.00460011 I, -0.00634031 - 0.00363047 I, -0.00291584 - 
   0.00265616 I, 0.000516539 - 0.00167714 I, 
   0.00395679 - 0.000693374 I, 0.00740485 + 0.000295169 I, 
   0.0108607 + 0.00128853 I, 0.0143242 + 0.00228673 I, 
   0.0177954 + 0.00328981 I, 
   0.0212742 + 0.0042978 I, -0.0134351 - 0.0052693 I, -0.0100307 - 
    0.00430232 I, -0.0066184 - 0.00333073 I, -0.00319813 - 0.00235449 I,
    0.00023004 - 0.00137356 I, 0.00366605 - 0.000387905 I, 
   0.00710985 + 0.000602501 I, 0.0105614 + 0.0015977 I, 
   0.0140206 + 0.00259772 I, 0.0174875 + 0.00360259 I, 
    0.020962 + 0.00461235 I, -0.0137129 - 0.00497358 I, -0.0103126 - 
   0.00400463 I, -0.00690446 - 0.00303109 I, -0.00348836 - 
   0.00205291 I, -0.0000643857 - 0.00107008 I, 
   0.00336741 - 0.000082544 I, 0.00680697 + 0.000909722 I, 
   0.0102543 + 0.00190676 I, 0.0137092 + 0.00290859 I, 
  0.0171718 + 0.00391526 I, 
  0.020642 + 0.00492679 I, -0.0139986 - 0.00467799 I, -0.0106025 - 
 0.00370707 I, -0.00719845 - 0.00273158 I, -0.00378649 - 
  0.00175149 I, -0.000366682 - 0.000766748 I, 
 0.00306092 + 0.000222667 I, 0.00649628 + 0.00121679 I, 
 0.00993933 + 0.00221566 I, 0.01339 + 0.00321931 I, 
 0.0168484 + 0.00422777 I, 
  0.0203142 + 0.00524107 I, -0.0142923 - 0.00438258 I, -0.0109003 - 
 0.0034097 I, -0.0075003 - 0.00243226 I, -0.00409246 - 
   0.00145024 I, -0.000676795 - 0.000463604 I, 
  0.00274664 + 0.000527689 I, 0.00617782 + 0.00152367 I, 
  0.00961667 + 0.00252438 I, 0.0130632 + 0.00352984 I, 
 0.0165172 + 0.00454009 I, 
 0.0199788 + 0.00555516 I, -0.0145938 - 0.00408739 I, -0.0112058 - 
 0.00311254 I, -0.00780995 - 0.00213316 I, -0.00440621 - 
  0.00114922 I, -0.000994663 - 0.000160684 I, 
  0.00242464 + 0.000832488 I, 0.00585165 + 0.00183033 I, 
  0.00928633 + 0.00283287 I, 0.0127286 + 0.00384014 I, 
  0.0161785 + 0.00485218 I, 
  0.0196359 + 0.00586902 I, -0.0149032 - 0.00379246 I, -0.0115192 - 
   0.00281564 I, -0.00812735 - 0.00183432 I, -0.00472768 - 
   0.000848461 I, -0.00132023 + 0.000141978 I, 
   0.00209496 + 0.00113703 I, 0.00551784 + 0.00213672 I, 
   0.00894838 + 0.0031411 I, 0.0123865 + 0.00415019 I, 
   0.0158322 + 0.00516403 I, 
   0.0192854 + 0.00618264 I, -0.0152202 - 0.00349781 I, -0.0118403 - 
    0.00251903 I, -0.00845244 - 0.00153577 I, -0.00505682 - 
    0.000547991 I, -0.00165343 + 0.000444347 I, 
     0.00175768 + 0.00144128 I, 0.00517646 + 0.00244283 I, 
     0.00860288 + 0.00344905 I, 0.0120369 + 0.00445996 I, 
     0.0154784 + 0.00547559 I, 
     0.0189275 + 0.00649599 I, -0.0155449 - 0.00320349 I, -0.012169 - 
     0.00222275 I, -0.00878515 - 0.00123755 I, -0.00539355 - 
    0.000247844 I, -0.00199419 + 0.000746397 I, 
    0.00141285 + 0.00174521 I, 0.00482757 + 0.00274863 I, 
     0.0082499 + 0.00375669 I, 0.0116798 + 0.00476942 I, 
     0.0151172 + 0.00578686 I, 
      0.0185622 + 0.00680904 I, -0.0158773 - 0.00290952 I, -0.0125052 - 
     0.00192682 I, -0.00912541 - 0.000939676 I, -0.0057378 + 
    0.0000519521 I, -0.00234246 + 0.0010481 I, 0.00106057 + 0.0020488 I,
    0.00447125 + 0.00305408 I, 0.00788953 + 0.00406399 I, 
    0.0113154 + 0.00507855 I, 0.0147487 + 0.0060978 I, 
    0.0181896 + 0.00712177 I};
```

This is the list of coordinate z:

```
    z = {0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
 0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
  0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
  0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 
  0.026000000000000002`, 0.026500000000000003`, 
  0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 
 0.028999999999999998`, 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 
  0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
  0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
  0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 
 0.026000000000000002`, 0.026500000000000003`, 
 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 
 0.028999999999999998`, 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 
 0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
 0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 
 0.026000000000000002`, 0.026500000000000003`, 
 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 
 0.028999999999999998`, 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 
  0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
 0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 
 0.026000000000000002`, 0.026500000000000003`, 
 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 
 0.028999999999999998`, 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 
 0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
 0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 0.025500000000000002`, 
 0.026000000000000002`, 0.026500000000000003`, 
 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 
 0.028999999999999998`, 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`, 0.025`, 
 0.025500000000000002`, 0.026000000000000002`, 
 0.026500000000000003`, 0.027000000000000003`, 0.0275`, 
 0.028000000000000004`, 0.0285`, 0.028999999999999998`, 
 0.029500000000000002`, 0.03`};
```

data of coordinate x:

```
    x = {0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 
  0.075`, 0.075`, 0.075`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`,
 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.0755`, 0.076`, 
 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.076`, 
 0.076`, 0.076`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 
 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.0765`, 0.077`, 
 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.077`, 
 0.077`, 0.077`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 
0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.0775`, 0.078`, 
0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 0.078`, 
0.078`, 0.078`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 
0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.0785`, 0.079`, 
0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 0.079`, 
0.079`, 0.079`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 
0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.0795`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 
0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`, 0.08`};

    fcon = Conjugate[f];
    if = Interpolation[Transpose[{z, x, f}]]
InterpolatingFunction[{{0.025, 0.03}, {0.075, 0.08}}, <>]
a[z_, x_] =(z*Derivative[0, 1][if] - x*Derivative[1, 0][if])
c[z_, x_] = fcon[z, x]*a[z, x]
 numerator =NIntegrate[c[z, x], {z, 0.025, 0.03}, {x, 0.075, 0.08}]
 absf[z_, x_] = (Abs[f])^2
   denominator = 
   NIntegrate[absf[z, x], {z, 0.025, 0.03}, {x, 0.075, 0.08}]
   result = numerator/denominator
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1313336

Comment: See mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1423/4999

Comment: My question is no more in community wolfram.